# How to pay users directly via Stripe?

Tags: ios, paypal, swiftui, stripe-payments

I want to pay users a one-off fixed $20 payment for completing a task within my iOS app.

I would like the user to be able to add their payment card within the app, and then when they complete the task the money goes directly to their payment card.

I have read [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect), however it seems the user has to leave the app and make their own Stripe account on Stripe's website, which is alot of work on the user end.

Is there an easier way for the user to add their payment card/verification only within my iOS app?

Or is there another provider such as PayPal that may offer this natively on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're user will have to create a Stripe Account to receive funds (i.e. get money which does not comes from a transaction they've initiated - like a refund -).

But no, they don't have to "create a Stripe Account", there's a product named **connect express** (https://stripe.com/fr/connect/express). Then you'll fully manage the account.

Please note that **it is not the primary goal**, of Stripe Connect which was built to allow products like marketplaces. Not one time shoot payments (please read their ToS before starting coding).

Moreover (but it's not a dev perspective), as a user I'd be a bit afraid of giving my CC number with a message saying "Hey give us your card, we'll send you $20". It look like this Scam you receive in inbox saying that you'll receive $13 M, in exchange of the transfer fees.

I don't know any PSP which offer that, for a specific reason, sending money to users is **extremely** regulated, as it's very borderline with **money laundering**.

If you really want to send money, for a dev perspective I'd go with collecting IBAN (safer, and you basically can't withdraw money with only such a piece of information). And work with Transferwise / IbanFirst APIs. But no Swift / SwiftUI here you'll have to write backend code.

Comment: Actually, you can withdraw money if you just have the IBAN. There is no second factor yet. I work in fraud prevention and unsolicited withdrawls happen a lot. 

The account holder name is usually collected but often not checked by banks if the amount is "small" (that could be 300 €, and is decided by the bank without any public disclosure).